# How to retrieve more than 1 translation option for 1 submitted item in V3 Text Translator?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

It seems that in V2 it was possible to set how many translations you wanted returned from the API. I am new to the service and with V3 I have not found a method or parameter that lets me get more than the one translation that the API 'assumes' that I want.

For example, searching the phrasal verb 'pick up' alone returns 'podniesc' in Polish. Searching 'pick up from the airport' returns 'odbior z lotniska', 'odbior' being the other meaning of pick up, i.e. collect. I would like to have multiple options returned without needing to add additional context.

Answer (score 1):

The Dictionary function of the Translator Text API returns rich information about the word or phrase passed in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-dictionary-lookup

Answer (score 0):

Alternative translations are not part of Translator Text API v3. There's a possibility in the future to include this feature though no promises.

Comment: That's a shame, did it exist for v2? That's a little bit of a deal breaker for me, unfortunately, and it's a shame, because the rest of the functionality is precisely what I'm looking for. Plus, the value is good (free up to 2,000,000 characters). But, as this is pretty critical, I might have to go to the big G and pay up 20 for their 1,000,000 character allowance :/

Comment: After testing Google they too only return one word translations. I don't suppose you would be able to advise on any service out there that does multiple translations? Many thanks!